# Spaces that have the Mandelbrot set as a covering space and Topological properties of the Mandelbrot set

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is just kind of a fun question that I've wanted to look into, but I lack the complex analysis background and time to do so. Essentially, I'm wondering if there are any interesting and/or well-known spaces that the mandelbrot set serves as a covering space for. If so, can anyone provide me with a link to a source that constructs/finds such a space and possibly provides a visual of it? In general, I'm also very interested in the topological properties of the mandelbrot set, so any information on that matter that does not rely on complex analysis would be appreciated as well. If this question is somehow obtuse or trivial, please keep in mind that, while I am currently finishing up my first graduate level algebraic topology course, I'm still an undergraduate and kind of a scatterbrain. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, about the title. I meant "Topological Properties", not "Topology Properties". I'm new to this website and don't know how I would fix this typo.

Comment: Click [edit] below your post. Or the link my comment.

Comment: @user Thanks, I completely missed the "share, cite, ect." options below the post.

Comment: I don't know much about the Mandlebrot set, but after a little googling, it appears that it is simply connected.  It also appears that it is unknown whether or not it is path connected, or locally (path) connected.  I also get the impression that these are deep questions.

Comment: @Charlie, Hmm, my guess then is that we probably don't know enough about the local properties of the Mandelbrot set for this question to be answerable. That's unfortunate.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.  At the same time, it could be the universal cover of something.  One may be able to get at that something by looking at the homeomorphisms of the Mandelbrot set that have no fixed points since these would be candidates for deck transformations.  This link:
https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/03/03-529.pdf
has info about homeos.  Of course, this approach is super naive.

Comment: @Charlie, Yeah, the fact that universal covering spaces often have fractal structures or require a certain degree of self similarity is part of why I find this question so interesting. I appreciate the link, I'll probably look it over when my final exams end.